# Load var n from localStorage and loop n times

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm trying to learn JS and this is my little app.

Every time I press the "INSTANTIATE" button, it instantiates a tomatoe.png in my `<div>`.

When the user reloads the page, the tomatoe.png should appear as many times as they've pressed the "INSTANTIATE" button.

This is the code. For this purpose, I created a variable (`i`), and it increments on every button press.

I planned to save this variable into `localStorage`, and when the page gets reloaded, I want to call a loop function that instantiates the tomatoe.png `i` times.

```js
function popUp() {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "tomato.png";
  var src = document.getElementById("header");
  src.appendChild(img);
  i++;
  localStorage.setItem("apples", i);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="popUp()">INSTANTIATE</button>
<div id="header"></div>
```

So, when the user reloads the page, as many tomatoes should appear as many times they've pressed the button.

I think I have to use a loop, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to declare `i` outside your function (in case you haven't done it already) and give it a value of zero, if it isn't exist in the Local Storage:

```js
let i = localStorage.getItem("apples") || 0;
```

Then, create a loop, that loops `i` times:

```js
for(let n = 0; n < i; n++){}
```

And finally, just create tomatoes:

```js
const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "tomato.png";
const src = document.getElementById("header");
src.appendChild(img);
```

So, the full code should look like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  function popUp() {
    createTomato()
    i++;
    localStorage.setItem("apples", i);
  }

  function createTomato() {
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "tomato.png";
    const src = document.getElementById("header");
    src.appendChild(img);
  }

  document.getElementById("instantiate").addEventListener("click", popUp)

  let i = localStorage.getItem("apples") || 0;

  for (let n = 0; n < i; n++) createTomato();
})
```

```html
<button id="instantiate">INSTANTIATE</button>
<div id="header"></div>
```

Try it on [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/XWJwBKb)

Comment: thank you for the answer and when does this loop get called  ? Do i have to call it ?

Comment: @HakkiUzel Since the loop isn't inside a function, it runs when the page is loaded. However, since the loop interacts with the DOM, you should wrap it a function, that listens for the `load` (or even better, the `DOMContentLoaded`) event. I'll edit my answer to show how.

Comment: @HakkiUzel Now it should... See my edit! Just to clarify, the runnable example still doesn't work, because StackSnippets use cross-origin sandboxed iframes, that prevent access to the Local Storage

Comment: thank you for trying to help me but it doesnt works :(

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:15)
7index.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: popUp is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:14)

Comment: @HakkiUzel It works for me... Try this [codepen:](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/XWJwBKb)

Answer (score 1):

Just get the item in `localStorage` and loop until it reaches `0`, creating a new image each time (`localStorage` don't works in StackOverflow snippets here because of security reasons, but you get the point).

```js
var i = 0;
function popUp() {
    newImage();
    i++;
    localStorage.setItem("apples", i);
}
function newImage() {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "tomato.png";
    var src = document.getElementById("header");
    src.appendChild(img);
}
var oldi = Number(localStorage.getItem("apples"));
while (oldi > 0) {
    oldi--;
    newImage();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="popUp()">INSTANTIATE</button>
<div id="header"></div>
```